# SQL Express 2012 error when installing vCenter Update Manager 6.x

Tags: sql, vmware-vcenter

When installing a fresh VUM 6.0u1 VM I ran into an issue where if you choose to use the free MS SQL Express 2012 DB you get an error that says 'SQL Installation was not successful'. If you try to run the SQL Express installed directing from the 'redist' directory of the .ISO file you see more detail, specifically about the installation user account not having the right privileges.

Comment: Make sure you add the .NET 3.5 feature. I've seen this when .net 3.5 was not installed and the sources were not available without getting them from the installation ISO/CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [THIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2000257) MS knowledge base article which makes you add three additional local policy privileges to the user account you're trying to install from. Remember to apply all THREE privileges (backup, debug and manage audit) and also logout and back in again before trying again.